# typescript sublime text3 plugin does not create *.js files

Tags: typescript, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I installed the microsoft sublime text plugin. Everything seems to work, but it does not create the javascript file "test.js" on the fly. I use sublimetext3 build 3083 with Windows 8.1 32 bit.

Here is a very simple example.

test.ts

```
    var s: string;
    s = 'Hello Typescript';
```

tsconfig.js

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "watch":true,
        "version":true,
        "diagnostics":true
   }
```

}

console log

```
 DPI scale: 1
startup, version: 3083 windows x32 channel: stable
executable: /D/Programme/Sublime Text Build 3083/sublime_text.exe
working dir: /D/Programme/Sublime Text Build 3083
packages path: /D/Programme/Sublime Text Build 3083/Data/Packages
state path: /D/Programme/Sublime Text Build 3083/Data/Local
zip path: /D/Programme/Sublime Text Build 3083/Packages
zip path: /D/Programme/Sublime Text Build 3083/Data/Installed Packages
ignored_packages: ["Vintage"]
pre session restore time: 1.03824
startup time: 1.14724
first paint time: 1.15124
reloading plugin Default.block
reloading plugin Default.comment
reloading plugin Default.copy_path
reloading plugin Default.delete_word
reloading plugin Default.detect_indentation
reloading plugin Default.duplicate_line
reloading plugin Default.echo
reloading plugin Default.exec
reloading plugin Default.fold
reloading plugin Default.font
reloading plugin Default.goto_line
reloading plugin Default.history_list
reloading plugin Default.indentation
reloading plugin Default.kill_ring
reloading plugin Default.mark
reloading plugin Default.new_templates
reloading plugin Default.open_context_url
reloading plugin Default.open_file_settings
reloading plugin Default.open_in_browser
reloading plugin Default.pane
reloading plugin Default.paragraph
reloading plugin Default.paste_from_history
reloading plugin Default.quick_panel
reloading plugin Default.save_on_focus_lost
reloading plugin Default.scroll
reloading plugin Default.set_unsaved_view_name
reloading plugin Default.side_bar
reloading plugin Default.sort
reloading plugin Default.swap_line
reloading plugin Default.switch_file
reloading plugin Default.symbol
reloading plugin Default.transform
reloading plugin Default.transpose
reloading plugin Default.trim_trailing_white_space
reloading plugin CSS.css_completions
reloading plugin Diff.diff
reloading plugin HTML.encode_html_entities
reloading plugin HTML.html_completions
reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.00-package_control
reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.02-bz2
reloading plugin DocBlockr.__init__
reloading plugin DocBlockr.jsdocs
reloading plugin LESS.less_completions
reloading plugin Package Control.bootstrap
reloading plugin Package Control.Package Control
reloading plugin PackageResourceViewer.package_resource_viewer
reloading plugin PackageResourceViewer.package_resources
reloading plugin SideBarEnhancements.SideBar
reloading plugin SideBarEnhancements.SideBarAPI
reloading plugin SideBarEnhancements.SideBarDefaultDisable
reloading plugin SublimeLinter-jshint.linter
SublimeLinter: jshint linter loaded 
reloading plugin SublimeLinter-json.linter
SublimeLinter: json linter loaded 
reloading plugin PlainTasks.PlainTasks
reloading plugin SublimeCodeIntel.ordereddict
reloading plugin SublimeCodeIntel.SublimeCodeIntel
reloading plugin SublimeLinter.commands
reloading plugin SublimeLinter.sublimelinter
reloading plugin TypeScript.TypeScript
2015-05-02 03:11:22,067: INFO: Logging configured to log to file: D:\Programme\Sublime Text Build 3083\Data\Packages\TypeScript\TS.log
2015-05-02 03:11:22,067: WARNING: TypeScript plugin initialized.
plugins loaded
SublimeLinter: debug mode: off 
initialize typescript...
3083
spawning node module: D:\Programme\Sublime Text Build 3083\Data\Packages\TypeScript\tsserver\tsserver.js
Found node executable at node
request: {"arguments": {"hostInfo": "Sublime Text version 3083", "formatOptions": {"tabSize": 4, "indentSize": 4}}, "type": "request", "seq": 1, "command": "configure"}
ref view not found
request: {"arguments": {"file": "C:\\Users\\mhueb_000\\Documents\\Projekte\\typetest\\test.ts"}, "type": "request", "seq": 2, "command": "open"}
request: {"arguments": {"files": ["C:\\Users\\mhueb_000\\Documents\\Projekte\\typetest\\test.ts"], "delay": 200}, "type": "request", "seq": 3, "command": "geterr"}
response: {"seq":0,"type":"response","command":"configure","request_seq":1,"success":true}

request: {"arguments": {"offset": 14, "file": "C:\\Users\\mhueb_000\\Documents\\Projekte\\typetest\\test.ts", "line": 2}, "type": "request", "seq": 4, "command": "quickinfo"}
queue timeout
request: {"arguments": {"files": ["C:\\Users\\mhueb_000\\Documents\\Projekte\\typetest\\test.ts"], "delay": 500}, "type": "request", "seq": 5, "command": "geterr"}
request: {"arguments": {"offset": 14, "file": "C:\\Users\\mhueb_000\\Documents\\Projekte\\typetest\\test.ts", "line": 2}, "type": "request", "seq": 6, "command": "quickinfo"}
response: {"seq":0,"type":"response","command":"quickinfo","request_seq":4,"success":false,"message":"No content available."}

response: {"seq":0,"type":"response","command":"quickinfo","request_seq":6,"success":false,"message":"No content available."}

request: {"arguments": {"offset": 15, "file": "C:\\Users\\mhueb_000\\Documents\\Projekte\\typetest\\test.ts", "line": 2}, "type": "request", "seq": 7, "command": "quickinfo"}
response: {"seq":0,"type":"response","command":"quickinfo","request_seq":7,"success":false,"message":"No content available."}

event: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"syntaxDiag","body":{"file":"C:/Users/mhueb_000/Documents/Projekte/typetest/test.ts","diagnostics":[]}}

request: {"arguments": {"offset": 14, "file": "C:\\Users\\mhueb_000\\Documents\\Projekte\\typetest\\test.ts", "line": 2}, "type": "request", "seq": 8, "command": "quickinfo"}
event: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"semanticDiag","body":{"file":"C:/Users/mhueb_000/Documents/Projekte/typetest/test.ts","diagnostics":[]}}

response: {"seq":0,"type":"response","command":"quickinfo","request_seq":8,"success":false,"message":"No content available."}

request: {"arguments": {"offset": 14, "file": "C:\\Users\\mhueb_000\\Documents\\Projekte\\typetest\\test.ts", "line": 2}, "type": "request", "seq": 9, "command": "quickinfo"}
request: {"arguments": {"offset": 14, "file": "C:\\Users\\mhueb_000\\Documents\\Projekte\\typetest\\test.ts", "line": 2}, "type": "request", "seq": 10, "command": "quickinfo"}
response: {"seq":0,"type":"response","command":"quickinfo","request_seq":9,"success":false,"message":"No content available."}

response: {"seq":0,"type":"response","command":"quickinfo","request_seq":10,"success":false,"message":"No content available."}

request: {"arguments": {"offset": 13, "file": "C:\\Users\\mhueb_000\\Documents\\Projekte\\typetest\\test.ts", "line": 2}, "type": "request", "seq": 11, "command": "quickinfo"}
response: {"seq":0,"type":"response","command":"quickinfo","request_seq":11,"success":false,"message":"No content available."}

Package Control: Skipping automatic upgrade, last run at 2015-05-02 02:13:21, next run at 2015-05-02 03:13:21 or after
request: {"arguments": {"offset": 12, "file": "C:\\Users\\mhueb_000\\Documents\\Projekte\\typetest\\test.ts", "line": 2}, "type": "request", "seq": 12, "command": "quickinfo"}
response: {"seq":0,"type":"response","command":"quickinfo","request_seq":12,"success":false,"message":"No content available."}

request: {"arguments": {"offset": 11, "file": "C:\\Users\\mhueb_000\\Documents\\Projekte\\typetest\\test.ts", "line": 2}, "type": "request", "seq": 13, "command": "quickinfo"}
response: {"seq":0,"type":"response","command":"quickinfo","request_seq":13,"success":false,"message":"No content available."}

request: {"arguments": {"offset": 10, "file": "C:\\Users\\mhueb_000\\Documents\\Projekte\\typetest\\test.ts", "line": 2}, "type": "request", "seq": 14, "command": "quickinfo"}
response: {"seq":0,"type":"response","command":"quickinfo","request_seq":14,"success":false,"message":"No content available."}

request: {"arguments": {"offset": 9, "file": "C:\\Users\\mhueb_000\\Documents\\Projekte\\typetest\\test.ts", "line": 2}, "type": "request", "seq": 15, "command": "quickinfo"}
response: {"seq":0,"type":"response","command":"quickinfo","request_seq":15,"success":false,"message":"No content available."}

request: {"arguments": {"offset": 8, "file": "C:\\Users\\mhueb_000\\Documents\\Projekte\\typetest\\test.ts", "line": 2}, "type": "request", "seq": 16, "command": "quickinfo"}
response: {"seq":0,"type":"response","command":"quickinfo","request_seq":16,"success":false,"message":"No content available."}

request: {"arguments": {"offset": 7, "file": "C:\\Users\\mhueb_000\\Documents\\Projekte\\typetest\\test.ts", "line": 2}, "type": "request", "seq": 17, "command": "quickinfo"}
response: {"seq":0,"type":"response","command":"quickinfo","request_seq":17,"success":false,"message":"No content available."}

request: {"arguments": {"offset": 6, "file": "C:\\Users\\mhueb_000\\Documents\\Projekte\\typetest\\test.ts", "line": 2}, "type": "request", "seq": 18, "command": "quickinfo"}
response: {"seq":0,"type":"response","command":"quickinfo","request_seq":18,"success":false,"message":"No content available."}

Could not import subprocess32 module, falling back to subprocess module
request: {"arguments": {"insertString": "h", "offset": 6, "file": "C:\\Users\\mhueb_000\\Documents\\Projekte\\typetest\\test.ts", "endLine": 2, "endOffset": 6, "line": 2}, "type": "request", "seq": 19, "command": "change"}
request: {"arguments": {"insertString": "", "offset": 7, "file": "C:\\Users\\mhueb_000\\Documents\\Projekte\\typetest\\test.ts", "endLine": 2, "endOffset": 8, "line": 2}, "type": "request", "seq": 20, "command": "change"}
request: {"arguments": {"files": ["C:\\Users\\mhueb_000\\Documents\\Projekte\\typetest\\test.ts"], "delay": 500}, "type": "request", "seq": 21, "command": "geterr"}
event: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"syntaxDiag","body":{"file":"C:/Users/mhueb_000/Documents/Projekte/typetest/test.ts","diagnostics":[]}}

event: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"semanticDiag","body":{"file":"C:/Users/mhueb_000/Documents/Projekte/typetest/test.ts","diagnostics":[]}}

request: {"arguments": {"offset": 7, "file": "C:\\Users\\mhueb_000\\Documents\\Projekte\\typetest\\test.ts", "line": 2}, "type": "request", "seq": 22, "command": "quickinfo"}
request: {"arguments": {"offset": 7, "file": "C:\\Users\\mhueb_000\\Documents\\Projekte\\typetest\\test.ts", "line": 2}, "type": "request", "seq": 23, "command": "quickinfo"}
response: {"seq":0,"type":"response","command":"quickinfo","request_seq":22,"success":false,"message":"No content available."}

response: {"seq":0,"type":"response","command":"quickinfo","request_seq":23,"success":false,"message":"No content available."}

request: {"arguments": {"offset": 7, "file": "C:\\Users\\mhueb_000\\Documents\\Projekte\\typetest\\test.ts", "line": 2}, "type": "request", "seq": 24, "command": "quickinfo"}
response: {"seq":0,"type":"response","command":"quickinfo","request_seq":24,"success":false,"message":"No content available."}
```

Comment: Do you have node installed?

Comment: I am a node developer. Could it be, that for compiling(building) I need an  extra build task for tsc.exe? I thought this would run automatic!?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ts[1.5.0-beta] file watcher with custom build file:

> Tools > Build System > New Build System...

```
{
    "cmd": ["tsc.cmd", "-p", "."]
}
```

> -p DIRECTORY  Compile the project in the given directory.
>
> "." - directory to tsconfig.json

After build (ctrl+B) compiler will watch files

But i'm using [ArcticTypescript](https://github.com/Phaiax/ArcticTypescript) and [tslint](https://github.com/lavrton/SublimeLinter-contrib-tslint) plugin instead of this.